# OSX AFP authentication

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, authentication, afp

I've enabled file sharing (AFP) on my iMac so that I can access it via our MacBook. I've also created a directory `~/shared/family` that I have shared to specific user accounts.

When I use the Finder on my MacBook, I see my iMac computer listed, and I can see my `~/Public` directory on the iMac, but I can't see `~/shared/family`.

How do I authenticate from my MacBook to my iMac? That seems like it's the missing step.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing out on  "**Connect As...**". So you identify not as Guest but as a certain user you added for that family-share.

[Connect As...](http://cl.ly/FVZ1)

The button can also be found in the top right, when already in folder-view:

[Connect As... bar](http://cl.ly/FVMO)